# Joomla EasyDiscuss and UTF-8 alias issue

Tags: unicode, joomla

I'm using  Joomla EasyDiscuss component for running a discussion community. And that is for Bengali. Unfortunately the component isn't supported for UNICODE alias, as I invested already, at this moment it's not possible to move to another one. And their support told me that they will release a fix with their next release. So now can anyone help me by suggesting a temporary fix?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you mean the [EasyDiscuss extension by StackIdeas](http://stackideas.com/easydiscuss/whatsnew.html), which runs on top of the [Joomla](http://joomla.org/) content management system. (*i.e.* it's not really correct to say the "Joomla EasyDiscuss" component; the Joomla folks didn't make EasyDiscuss.)

StackIdeas announced [version 2.0 of EasyDiscuss](http://stackideas.com/blog/entry/easydiscuss-20-released.html) on January 9, 2012, after you posted your question. I don't see anything on their site which says that version 2.0 supports the full complement of Unicode characters, or languages beyond Western European, or international use, or anything like that.

However, I was able to get on their demo site and create a category [*Testing Only テスト*](http://play.stackideas.com/discussions/index/testing-only-%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88.html), which includes the Japanese characters テスト ("test") in both the title and alias. Check the link, which was copied from the demo site: the URL includes the string `%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88`.  (N.B. The demo site might get cleared periodically, so by the time you follow the link, this text might be gone.)

But it sure looks like EasyDiscuss 2.0 has some degree of support for non-Latin text in aliases.

There is a comment thread on the 2.0 announcement page. I've put a pointer to this question there. Maybe the StackIdeas folks will come here and give a definitive answer.

**Update**: the EasyDiscuss 2.0 announcement page now has this reply, which I think is official: "The latest version 2.0 already comes with unicode support and I think you have tested it yourself in our Demo page. All you need to do is activate it in the EasyDiscuss backend: `Settings -> General -> SEO` and click `YES` to allow unicode aliases. :D Thanks for the input! We will add this feature in the what's new page."

Comment: If you go to the Components tab in Joomla, there is EasyDiscuss. Also, if you manage this extension, it is of type Component in the database. Hence the confusion between it being an extension, even to those who have been doing it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading the latest version from the site? This issue should be fixed in their latest version as it supports unicode aliases.

Comment: Can you provide a link to change notes that talks about unicode aliasing?